# Calculating resistance for zenor diodes?

Tags: zener

[image]

I am an electronics student, and I was set some homework online. Am not having trouble with the question itself but the theory. It says that the current through the resistor is the *same* as the maximum current that the diodes can safely handle, but as you can see, there are (V-out) volts being dissipating to the right, and a minimum required current going through the diode to maintain consistent voltage.

How could the current through the resistor be the same as the current through the diode, as voltage=J/C, or, joules per coulomb, so that means there must be some energy carried by the coulombs, and ultimately, some electrons. But then this is contradictory, wouldn't the current going through the resistor be the total current, the current dissipated to the right and current through the zener? Or... Is it that there isn't, then, any current passing at V-out? and it doesn't represent voltage being dissipated?